# Delete columns of a dataframe using several ranges

Tags: python, pandas

So i need to drop several columns of the same Dataframe, but i want to do it all at once

```
    df = pd.read_excel(archivo)
    df.drop(df.columns[5:24, 26:29, 32:33], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

This shoot me the error '*too many indices for array*'. I also try this:

```
    df = pd.read_excel(archivo)
    df.drop(df.columns[5:24], axis=1, inplace=True)
    df.drop(df.columns[26:29], axis=1, inplace=True)
    df.drop(df.columns[32:33], axis=1, inplace=True)
    df.drop(df.columns[35:38], axis=1, inplace=True)
    df.drop(df.columns[41:51], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

But i didnt work properly

Comment: What do you mean that it didn't work properly?

Answer (score 1):

How about this single line solution?

```
df = df[df.columns.difference(remove1).difference(remove2).difference(remove3).difference(remove4).difference(remove5)]
```

**Full code:**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=range(1,100))
print(df)
remove1 = range(5,26)  
remove2 = range(26,30)  
remove3 = range(32,34)  
remove4 = range(35,39)  
remove5 = range(41,52)  

df = df[df.columns.difference(remove1).difference(remove2).difference(remove3).difference(remove4).difference(remove5)]
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99]
Index: []

[0 rows x 99 columns]
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [1, 2, 3, 4, 30, 31, 34, 39, 40, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99]
Index: []
```

**DEMO:** https://repl.it/repls/HonoredFirstMicrokernel

Answer (score 0):

The second piece of code should work, but you will need to change the column ranges after each dropcolumns line. The position of the columns in the DataFrame will change.

In my opinion it may be better to drop columns based on names, for example if you run your code twice it'll drop the columns in those positions again. However if you used column names you'd get an error.

Comment: I use it, but i start counting index from the end.